# Django Sync DB in PyDev (Eclipse and Aptana) fails after answering "yes" to define superusers

Tags: python, django, aptana, pydev

What may be going on here?  This is a problem on two separate Macs of mine - one Eclipse install and one Aptana Studio.  After I answer "yes" to create a superuser the first time I Sync DB, I get these errors.

Performing Sync db outside of PyDev (via terminal, etc) seems to work fine.

> You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have
>   any superusers defined. Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):
>   yes Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mac2/Documents/workspace/helloworld/manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 443, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 382, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 371, in handle
>       return self.handle_noargs(**options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py",
>   line 110, in handle_noargs
>       emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py",
>   line 189, in emit_post_sync_signal
>       interactive=interactive, db=db)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py",
>   line 172, in send
>       response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/**init**.py",
>   line 73, in create_superuser
>       call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True, database=db)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 150, in call_command
>       return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
>       default_username = get_default_username()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/**init**.py",
>   line 105, in get_default_username
>       default_username = get_system_username()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/**init**.py",
>   line 85, in get_system_username
>       return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]) TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None Finished
>   "/Users/mac2/Documents/workspace/helloworld/manage.py syncdb"
>   execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error returned indicates that the call to `decode` is failing with a None argument:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/init.py", line 85, in get_system_username return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]) TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None Finished
```

The problem there is that `locale.getdefaultlocale()` returns a tuple with the environment variable `LANG` (see http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html). If you open terminal, where syncdb works, and type `echo $LANG`, my guess is you'll get something like `en_US.UTF-8`. Similarly, I imagine Python on your command line returns something like this:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

However, if you run that same command from within Eclipse, where the LANG environment variable isn't set, you get `(None, None)`.

Try setting the LANG environment variable in Eclipse (Run Configurations... > Environment), and then running syncdb. You might have to play a bit with where the variable is set (i.e., in the Run Config versus the Project itself). Does that fix the problem?

Comment: You can also set the environment variable in the `settings.py` of your Django project like that: `import os; os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'`.